# Corda running on Java 9

Tags: corda

Java 8 is going out of public support in September and can no longer be secured we need to know when the Corda platform will remove their dependency on Java 8 therefore, we need a Java 9 compatible version of Corda available with enough lead time that we can get in internally installed, tested, and deployed before September 2018.

Please, let us know your thoughts
 Javier

Answer (score 9):

We've done some initial work on Java 9 support already. For example we're setting Automatic-Module-Name on our JARs and worked on de-splitting our packages. I'm hoping we can focus on finishing this off and getting a Java 9 based version of Corda out some time next year. However, other features that are needed for deployment are taking priority.

For our enterprise offering we're switching to bundling the JRE ourselves, so the JVM version will not be a concern of the users, it will be our problem and we'll release JVM updates as part of Corda releases. This is the direction the Java platform is travelling anyway. Therefore, security fixes in the underlying runtime will be reviewed by us to see if they're applicable and trigger new enterprise Corda releases if necessary. Testing of the combinations will be on us.

Comment: We appreciate you have already started to work on Java 9 support. Are you able to tell us an estimated month for this completion? I believe all major organisation also have a red flag on all Java 8 application and require a plan for upgrade.
Regarding bundling JRE into Corda, is this only going to happen for the Enterprise version? If so, for the open source version would you continue to support the latest version of Java?

Comment: Corda relies heavly on http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/. But there seems barely any activity on the project and supported is limited to Java 8. Is this going to be addressed? maybe it would be worthwhile to drop quasar for something more common-place like https://projectreactor.io/ and avoid all the bytecode manipulations.