# Corda running on Java 9 - Follow up

Tags: java, corda

this is a follow up question about previously one [Corda running on Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769282/corda-running-on-java-9)

We appreciate you have already started to work on Java 9 support. Are you able to tell us an estimated month for this completion? I believe all major organisation also have a red flag on all Java 8 application and require a plan for upgrade. Regarding bundling JRE into Corda, is this only going to happen for the Enterprise version? If so, for the open source version would you continue to support the latest version of Java?

Thanks in advance

Javier

Comment: Who are you talking to?

Comment: I would like to have a response from Corda team.

Comment: You should contact them instead of posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

We aim to be on the latest release of Java to take advantage of its latest capabilities. However, we don't have a specific timeframe for Java 9 support at this time. We will communicate this in the near future via Corda.net.