# Corda Sample App Node Deployment Build Failure : JRE Compatibility Issue

Tags: java, log4j, build.gradle, blockchain, corda

Is Corda Node Deployment not supported on JRE greater than 1.8 ?
Quite surprised to know that Corda Nodes are not upward compatible with JRE versions higher than JRE 1.8. It is quite difficult to keep a specific JRE version for an Enterprise Application. I am getting the following error in Corda Sample App Deployment due to JRE incompatibility ?

> Bootstrapping local test network in
>   /Users/gokulalex/Apps/corda_apps/corda_samples/samples/cordapp-example/workflows-java/build/nodes Generating node directory for PartyA Generating node directory for
>   Notary Generating node directory for PartyC Generating node directory
>   for PartyB 2019-03-14 13:23:17,274 Task worker for ':' INFO Cannot
>   initialize scripting support because this JRE does not support it.
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineManager
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.(ScriptManager.java:69)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:216)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:548)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:637)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
>           at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
>           at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
>           at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
>           at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
>
> Error while generating node info file /Users/gokulalex/Apps/corda_apps/corda_samples/samples/cordapp-example/workflows-java/build/nodes/PartyB/logs
>   
>   Error: Unsupported Java version 9.0.1; currently only version 1.8 is supported.
>   
>   Error while generating node info file /Users/gokulalex/Apps/corda_apps/corda_samples/samples/cordapp-example/workflows-java/build/nodes/Notary/logs
>   
>   Error: Unsupported Java version 9.0.1; currently only version 1.8 is supported.
>   
>   Error while generating node info file /Users/gokulalex/Apps/corda_apps/corda_samples/samples/cordapp-example/workflows-java/build/nodes/PartyA/logs
>   
>   Error: Unsupported Java version 9.0.1; currently only version 1.8 is supported.
>   
>   Error while generating node info file /Users/gokulalex/Apps/corda_apps/corda_samples/samples/cordapp-example/workflows-java/build/nodes/PartyC/logs
>   
>   Error: Unsupported Java version 9.0.1; currently only version 1.8 is supported.
>
> > Task :workflows-java:deployNodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.corda.net/releases/M17-RC02/getting-set-up.html) it's mentioned that

> Corda runs in a JVM. JVM implementations other than Oracle JDK 8 are
>   not actively supported.

Also, there was already a similar question, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769282/corda-running-on-java-9).